# AVPlayerViewController video with swift 2.0 xcode 7 beta 3

Tags: avplayer, swift2, xcode7, ios9

I have done some pretty heavy digging I feel like and have not been able to find the reasons for my errors with playing video in an app with swift 2.0 in xcode 7...

I may be missing a bunch of stuff...I am new to adding video in an app but I have seen a bunch of different code on this topic as of late. Thanks for any help or pointers!

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation


class ProfileTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var moviePlayer : AVPlayerViewController!


    @IBAction func playButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("SampleVideo_1080x720_1mb.mp4", ofType:"mp4")

        let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)

        self.moviePlayer = AVPlayerViewController()

        if let player = self.moviePlayer {

            player.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
            player.view.sizeToFit()
            /* Scale the movie player to fit the aspect ratio */
            player.scalingMode = .AspectFit
            player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.None
            player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceType.File; player.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatMode.One;
            player.play()
            self.view.addSubview(player.view)



        }


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

"SampleVideo_1080x720_1mb.mp4", ofType:"mp4"

Shouldn't this be ""SampleVideo_1080x720_1mb", ofType:"mp4"

Otherwise looking for "SampleVideo_1080x720_1mb.mp4.mp4"

Answer (score 1):

i think the problem is the .mp4 at the end of pathForRecource.
instead of :
 `let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("SampleVideo_1080x720_1mb.mp4", ofType:"mp4")` , 
it should be this : `let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("SampleVideo_1080x720_1mb", ofType:"mp4")`